# Heroku app crashes after successfully started

Tags: java, spring, heroku, heroku-postgres

When I deploy my spring application it initializes with heroku postgres db and everything works fine, but then status changes to "crashed". If I run it with `heroku local` everything works fine.
logs:

```
2020-04-01T23:14:56.352610+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2020-04-01T23:14:56.356959+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2020-04-01T23:14:57.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-04-01T23:14:58.172994+00:00 app[web.1]: LOGBACK: No context given for c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@1021436681
2020-04-01T23:14:58.347661+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-01T23:14:58.347672+00:00 app[web.1]: .   ____          _            __ _ _
2020-04-01T23:14:58.347758+00:00 app[web.1]: /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2020-04-01T23:14:58.347824+00:00 app[web.1]: ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2020-04-01T23:14:58.347891+00:00 app[web.1]: \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2020-04-01T23:14:58.347959+00:00 app[web.1]: '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2020-04-01T23:14:58.348042+00:00 app[web.1]: =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2020-04-01T23:14:58.349377+00:00 app[web.1]: :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)
2020-04-01T23:14:58.349417+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-01T23:14:58.646256+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:14:58.641  INFO 4 --- [           main] c.s.s.ServerHospitalApplication          : Starting ServerHospitalApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on ee8bd841-dcb7-4af4-90f2-fb5330b4b247 with PID 4 (/app/target/server-hospital-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by u45481 in /app)
2020-04-01T23:14:58.647797+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:14:58.647  INFO 4 --- [           main] c.s.s.ServerHospitalApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-04-01T23:14:59.704318+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:14:59.702  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-04-01T23:14:59.796551+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:14:59.796  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 79ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-04-01T23:15:00.931272+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:15:00.931  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-04-01T23:15:00.946566+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:15:00.946  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-04-01T23:15:00.946955+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:15:00.946  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
2020-04-01T23:15:01.012734+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:15:01.012  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-04-01T23:15:01.013067+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:15:01.012  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2288 ms
2020-04-01T23:15:01.245799+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:15:01.245  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-04-01T23:15:01.339150+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:15:01.338  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-04-01T23:15:01.518879+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:15:01.518  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-04-01T23:15:01.652931+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:15:01.652  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-04-01T23:15:02.045903+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:15:02.045  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-04-01T23:15:02.080020+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:15:02.079  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
2020-04-01T23:15:04.111351+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:15:04.111  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-04-01T23:15:04.121608+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:15:04.121  INFO 4 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-04-01T23:15:04.702613+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:15:04.702  WARN 4 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-04-01T23:15:04.947395+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:15:04.947  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-04-01T23:15:05.444803+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:15:05.444  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-04-01T23:15:05.448231+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-01 23:15:05.448  INFO 4 --- [           main] c.s.s.ServerHospitalApplication          : Started ServerHospitalApplication in 8.023 seconds (JVM running for 9.091)
2020-04-01T23:16:25.088442+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-01T23:16:25.713713+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fx-server.herokuapp.com request_id=16a54f69-760a-4fa1-9813-93f4c5846440 fwd="93.85.72.168" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-04-01T23:16:25.935733+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fx-server.herokuapp.com request_id=e4b37c4b-a4bf-4411-803e-c9e15be13287 fwd="93.85.72.168" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: So. Ther problem is that tomcat doesn't dispatch requests to the servlets (int simply doesn't initialize dispatcher servlet). Any ideas ?

Comment: It looks like your app is binding to port `8080` which is probably not correct. Your application should bind to the `$PORT` environment variable. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/setting-the-http-port-for-java-applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. According to the heroku policy, your app will be started at the random port, that currently is free for usage. Your `Procfile` should look like this (for spring boot)

```
web: java -jar target/jarname.jar --server.port=$PORT
```

You also can use this as `application.properties` property.

Thanks to Malax for help.